# SharePoint 2013 - Set sub-site page has my site home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, I created a sub-site within my site collection.  When anyone logs in, I would like them to always go to my sub-site page location rather than the default.aspx page on the root, like this...

```
http://my-site/sub-site/pages/home.aspx
```

instead of this..

```
http://my-site/default.aspx
```

Is this possible in SharePoint 2013?  Are there settings for this from site settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Publishing features need to be activated in the site. First activate the **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure** by going to *Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration  -> Site collection features* . Then activate **SharePoint Server Publishing** by going to *Site Settings -> Site Actions -> Manage Site Features*. Now go into `Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Welcome Page`. Here, you can browse to sub site page and set that as the welcome page of the root site collection. However, if turning on Publishing features is not an option, then you may try to Edit the home page of the root site and add Script Editor webpart to the page and paste the following code into it.

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0"; url=http://www.subsitepagelocation">
```

This will redirect users to the new page immediately.