# SharePoint Online change site collection homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I write link `"company.sharepoint.com"` it will redirect me to the `company.sharepoint.com/SitePages/HomePage.aspx` which is my SiteCollection homepage. Is it posible to change redirect to "`company.sharepoint.com/intranet"` when I will write"`company.sharepoint.com"`?

Intranet is Subsite for that homepage teamsite because I wasn't experienced back then and I only created subsites instead of Site Collection. I have some data on intranet so I can't easily migrate. Thank you so much for the answers.

Comment: check this, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/128812/58747

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any of the suggestions above but short of disseminating a different url to your end users there is no "nice" way to address this. Bite the bullet now and fix it properly by moving your intranet back to the root.

Fix it now or you may regret not doing so for years to come...